# Curtain relocates and doesn't appear in render image or animation

Tags: rendering, animation, scale

I copied a curtain model to my blender files and made some modifications including scale and color. When I render the image or animation, the curtain disappears from the scene and relocates to a different location without saving my changes in terms of scaling. How can I render the curtains in the scene and allow for my changes to be saved in the render view and final rendering.

Comment: Simplified blend might be more helpful,.to let as see your setup. In meantime try to check if there is a keyframe for location /scale in your timeline.

Comment: tap ctrl-a and apply all transforms